# И другая версия появления детей

Tags: фразеология

Очень интересная дискуссия по поводу детей и капусты. А мне подумалось: ведь есть еще объяснение, что детей приносит аист. А она-то откуда взялась? Да, есть примета, что, если аисты свили гнездо на крыше, это к счастью, но ребенок, особенно в бедной многодетной семье, далеко не всегда такая уж радость.
Тогда почему именно аисты?

Answer (score 6):

Вот здесь подробно: [Почему детей приносит именно аист?](http://www.hint4.me/4871-pochemu-detey-prinosit-imenno-aist.html)

Во многих мировых культурах в древности эти птицы почитались как священные. По сей день они символизируют плодородие, возрождение, счастье и мир. Божественная птица запечатлена на старинных фресках, картинах, ей воздвигнуты статуи. В древней Македонии аистов чеканили на монетах, медики украшали ими свои щиты.
Ученые, пытающиеся проследить, где же все-таки зародилась эта красивая история, так и не пришли к однозначному мнению. Аист символизировал римскую Юнону, богиню-мать, покровительницу плодородия. Ей поклонялись и молились бесплодные женщины, жаждущие исцеления.
Найдены письмена, где указано, что именно эта птица, принимала участие в уходе за новорожденным Иисусом, выложив его колыбель своими перьями, чем заслужила пророчество подросшего Христа: «она отныне будет именоваться благословенной птицей и покровителем всех детей». Еще одной божественной наградой аисту стало долгожительство – 70 лет. На еврейском языке аист называется – «chasidah»,что переводится, как «добрый», «милосердный». Это слово многократно встречается в Библии, что подтверждает древность легенды о приносящем детей аисте.
Этимологи, исследовавшие немецкое слово «adebor» (аист), нашли в нем языческие корни. Образованное из нескольких частей, оно трактуется как «приносящий удачу» или же «приносящий детей».

Испокон веков прославляются благословенные качества этих птиц. Они – образцовые родители, преданные и заботливые дети, верные супруги. На самом деле – семейная жизнь аистов крайне нетипична для большинства других представителей животного мира. Пары формируются один раз и навсегда, если кто-нибудь из пары умирает, то оставшийся никогда не создаст новую семью. Семья строит гнездо на долгие годы и каждый раз после зимовки в теплых краях возвращается в него. А уход за престарелыми родителями просто фантастичен: они окружают их заботой, кормят и даже укрывают перьями, выщипывая их у себя.